# Translation of "I'm not sure I agree with you"

Tags: traduction

In English you can say "I'm not sure I agree with you" as a softer way of saying "I don't agree with you." Can we say the equivalent in French?

> Je ne suis pas sûr(e) que je sois d'accord.

I thought using the subjunctive here sounds odd, as the speaker is doubting his/her own opinion, but according to grammar rules it seems that it has to be so. Is this sentence idiomatic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say:

> Je crains de ne pas être d'accord.
>
> or: Je crains de ne pas être de votre avis.
>
> or: J'ai bien peur de ne pas être d'accord là-dessus.
>
> or: J'avoue ne pas être d'accord avec vous.

The "softer" use of the expression « je crains » in a different context:

> Je crains de ne pas être d'humeur pour bavarder.

The sentence that you suggests sounds as if you are indeed in two minds, rather than trying to tone it down.

Comment: We often use *bien* to soften down *craindre*. « Je crains bien ne pas être de votre avis » would probably be the most usual way to say this.

Comment: "craindre" means "to fear", a notion absent from "I'm not sure". "J'avoue" is an ugly language manner, trending these years but still semantically wrong.

Comment: J'aurais répondu sans aucune hésitation "je ne suis pas sûr d'être d'accord avec vous", mais je m'interroge maintenant : s'agit-il d'un anglicisme ?

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues Pourquoi s'agirait-il d'un anglicisme ? Ça veut dire ce que ça veut dire, en français comme en anglais ; il s'agit pour moi d'un euphémisme, tout simplement.

Comment: Personnellement, je n'utiliserait pas "de" après "crains": "je crains ne pas être d'accord" ou "Je crains ne pas être de votre avis". Peut-être que ça fait plus soutenu ?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't *"I'm not sure I agree with you"* just an euphemism? It doesn't sound idiomatic to me. If you want to soften something you are going to say, there are many ways, so why not saying you are not sure about it, yes.

In that case you could say *"je ne suis pas sûr(e) d'être d'accord"* or *"je ne suis pas sûr(e) que je suis d'accord"* (NOT *"que je sois"*).